# Growth direction of runtime stack

Tags: operating-system, stack, runtime

Why does the `runtime stack` always grow down? (from higher memory address to lower memory address)

Are there any constraints which result in this situation?

Is it determined by the Operating System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not always grow down.  It grows down on Intel hardware and is architecture-dependent.

Comment: Usually when storing data in memory, we put them in address-increasing sequence, such as arrays. However Intel uses the runtime stack by the opposite direction, is there any special concern for that?

Comment: Not really, no. It's maybe easier to grow the stack down 'cos then stack-arrays are at positive offsets to the current stack frame.